# Why does Xcode skip for loop code?

Tags: ios, methods

Just want to ask if this method `initWithNibName` ends, will the `logInIDArray` and `passwordArray` property become nil again?

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
//sharedLogInDataBase returns singleton
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    BNRLogInDataBase *logInDatabase = [BNRLogInDataBase sharedLogInDataBase];
    logInDatabase.logInIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    logInDatabase.passwordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
return self;
}
```

here's the singleton method

```
+(instancetype)sharedLogInDataBase
{
static BNRLogInDataBase * database = nil;
if (!nil) {
    database = [[BNRLogInDataBase alloc]initPrivate];
    }
return database;
}

-(instancetype)init
{
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Singleton" reason:@"use sharedLogInDataBase"              userInfo:nil];
}

-(instancetype)initPrivate
{
 self = [super init];

return self;
}
```

Comment: It depends on `sharedLogInDataBase` - is it really returning a singleton instance? And show the code where you have an issue, and describe what debugging has been done.

Comment: the `logInDatabase` object points the singleton object and hence it will be retained!!!

Comment: Guy's I know its stupid asking this question because whenever i add object into the properties i still get 0 object or 1 object only with each addition.

Comment: @Wain here's the code +(instancetype)sharedLogInDataBase
{
    static BNRLogInDataBase * database = nil;
    if (!nil) {
        database = [[BNRLogInDataBase alloc]initPrivate];
        }
    return database;
}

Comment: You should think over the design of the class BNRLogInDataBase. Its really a bad practice to instantiate properties in another class.

Comment: @saurabh sure, ill correct my way thanks for informing as I'm just a newbie in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should be:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedLogInDataBase
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Currently your `if (!nil)` is not doing what you expect it to...

Then, your `init` method should call your `initPrivate` method.

Comment: wait, but according to big nerd ranch that's how the book implements the singleton method. What do you mean my if(!nil) isn't working using static keeps the object alive right? i'll try your method also!

Comment: `nil` is equivalent to `false` / `NO` in that statement. So you're saying `if (!NO)`, which is `if (YES)`, so you're always executing and returning a new instance. The `dispatch_once` approach is much better + safer

Answer (score 1):

They cannot become nil because you instantiated them. Though they will be empty.

Comment: I'm having a tough time doing this because when i try to add object into both the properties, they're still zero even after adding it. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Are you sure that logInDatabase is really a singleton object? Because if not then you are using local variable that will be vanished after init. Make sure you really have ONE logInDatabase object.

Comment: please check the code up there I'm not sure I'm just a newbie in iOS programming.

Comment: I was actually right :) - your singleton was not really a singleton )

Comment: yea haha i should've replace the !nil with !variable, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will depends on:

- How you implemented your `BNRLogInDataBase` singleton, if you use a strong reference to keep the singleton instance `logInDatabase` will stay, if not it will be deallocated
- How you declared `logInIDArray` and `passwordArray` properties, if strong they will remain as long as `logInDatabase` exists, if weak they will become `nil`

```
if (!nil) {
    database = [[BNRLogInDataBase alloc]initPrivate];
}
```

Check your test, `nil` is always `false`, so `!nil` is always `true`, each time you call your singleton you get a different object !

Comment: please check the code up there i already upload my implementation of my singleton method